# I want to call register form in my popup , and it's call from default.xml via block

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to call register form in popup and i tried by below code from default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
   <container name="registerpopup" as="registerpopup" label="registerpopup" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="overlay" htmlId="registerPopup" after="page.main" before="footer.container">
       <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml" />
   </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

When i submit the form it nothing do, and not register any customer

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="registerpopup" as="registerpopup" label="registerpopup" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="overlay" htmlId="registerPopup" after="page.main" before="footer.container">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml">
       
    </container>
</referenceContainer>

Comment: @Abdul please find my code